# Adding a time stamp to SQLite table in C

Tags: c, sqlite, timestamp

I am attempting to migrate some code from python to C. Everything is going well except adding a timestamp to the SQlite3 table.

Here is the working Python code.

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLCValues(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [timestamp] timestamp, \
    x001 NUMERIC, x002 NUMERIC, x003 NUMERIC, x004 NUMERIC, x005 NUMERIC, x006 NUMERIC, x007 NUMERIC, x008 NUMERIC,\
    y001 NUMERIC, y002 NUMERIC, y003 NUMERIC, y004 NUMERIC, y005 NUMERIC, y006 NUMERIC,\
    x201 NUMERIC, x202 NUMERIC, x203 NUMERIC, x204 NUMERIC, x205 NUMERIC, x206 NUMERIC, x207 NUMERIC, x208 NUMERIC,\
    df1 REAL, df2  REAL, df3 REAL, df4 REAL)")

cur.execute("INSERT INTO PLCValues VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",\
            (datetime.now(), \
            regs1[0], regs1[1], regs1[2], regs1[3], regs1[4], regs1[5], regs1[6], regs1[7],\
            regs2[0], regs2[1], regs2[2], regs2[3], regs2[4], regs2[5],\
            regs3[0], regs3[1], regs3[2], regs3[3], regs3[4], regs3[5], regs3[6], regs3[7],\
            Temp/10, Humid/10, 0, 0))
```

In C, I had to change things a little. my date code is 2019-02-10 21:42:06 which is a approved format.

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLCValues(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \
    x001 NUMERIC, x002 NUMERIC, x003 NUMERIC, x004 NUMERIC, x005 NUMERIC, x006 NUMERIC, x007 NUMERIC, x008 NUMERIC,\
    x201 NUMERIC, x202 NUMERIC, x203 NUMERIC, x204 NUMERIC, x205 NUMERIC, x206 NUMERIC, x207 NUMERIC, x208 NUMERIC,\
    y001 NUMERIC, y002 NUMERIC, y003 NUMERIC, y004 NUMERIC, y005 NUMERIC, y006 NUMERIC,\
    df1 REAL, df2  REAL, df3 REAL, df4 REAL)";

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);


strftime(TimeStamp, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));

snprintf(sql, sizeof(sql), \
    "INSERT INTO PLCValues VALUES(%s, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %f, %f, %f, %f)", \
    TimeStamp, p.regs1[0], p.regs1[1], p.regs1[2], p.regs1[3], p.regs1[4], p.regs1[5], p.regs1[6], p.regs1[7],\
    p.regs2[0], p.regs2[1], p.regs2[2], p.regs2[3], p.regs2[4], p.regs2[5], p.regs2[6], p.regs2[7],\
    p.regs3[0], p.regs3[1], p.regs3[2], p.regs3[3], p.regs3[4], p.regs3[5], p.Temp, p.Humid, 0, 0);


int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);
```

When I run it, it gets hung up on the time string space

SQL error: near "21": syntax error

I have tried changing things around, but have limited experience with SQLite

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why aren't you preparing a statement and binding values to it? Trying to build a string with a SQL statement with arbitrary values directly in it is a really bad idea. You're doing it right in the python version... https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html

Comment: I will check into this. I have limited experience with SQLite. I was hoping to get off easy because I already had the SQL syntax

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code used to get this working. including the timestamp!

```
char *err_msg = 0;
   sqlite3_stmt *res;

   //pull current time
   char TimeStamp[20];
   time_t now = time(NULL);
   strftime(TimeStamp, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));
   printf("%s\n",TimeStamp);

   char *sql = "INSERT INTO PLCValues VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

   int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);

   if (rc == SQLITE_OK ) {

      //Bind the variables  
        sqlite3_bind_text(res, 1, TimeStamp, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 2, p.regs1[0]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 3, p.regs1[1]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 4, p.regs1[2]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 5, p.regs1[3]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 6, p.regs1[4]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 7, p.regs1[5]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 8, p.regs1[6]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 9, p.regs1[7]);

      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 10, p.regs2[0]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 11, p.regs2[1]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 12, p.regs2[2]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 13, p.regs2[3]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 14, p.regs2[4]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 15, p.regs2[5]);

      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 16, p.regs3[0]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 17, p.regs3[1]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 18, p.regs3[2]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 19, p.regs3[3]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 20, p.regs3[4]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 21, p.regs3[5]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 22, p.regs3[6]);
      sqlite3_bind_int(res, 23, p.regs3[7]);

        sqlite3_bind_double(res, 24, p.Temp);      
      sqlite3_bind_double(res, 25, p.Humid);
      sqlite3_bind_double(res, 26, 0);
      sqlite3_bind_double(res, 27, 0);

   }else{

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return -1;
   } 

   int step = sqlite3_step(res);

   if (step == SQLITE_ROW) {

      printf("%s: ", sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));
      printf("%s\n", sqlite3_column_text(res, 1));

   } 

   sqlite3_finalize(res);

}
```